# Given one side of a regular polygon, find the remaining sides

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math, geometry, turtle-graphics

We are given:

- the number of sides of a regular polygon
- one side defined by coordinates (x1, y1) and (x2, y2)

I have to find out the remaining coordinates. How can I do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show your code and the exact problem you're having.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose we have a [turtle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turtle_graphics) that has drawn one segment of an `n`-sided regular polygon by moving from `x1, y1` to `x2, y2`. To draw the remaining sides, we do this `n-1` times:

- turn by a certain angle
- move forward a certain distance

The angle that we have to turn is 360/`n` degrees. For example, if we're drawing a triangle, the turtle has to turn 120 degrees after each segment. If we're drawing the triangle clockwise, we subtract 120 degrees from the current orientation of the turtle. If we're drawing it counterclockwise, we add 120 degrees.

The distance to move forward is the length of the first segment. We can calculate the length of the segment using the [Pythagorean theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem). In JavaScript, we can implement it thus:

```
var dx = x2-x1,
    dy = y2-y1,
    length = Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
```

The initial orientation of the turtle is the same as the angle of the first line segment, which we can calculate by taking the inverse cosine of `dx/length`:

```
var angle = Math.acos(dx/length);
if (dy < 0) {
  angle = 2*Math.PI - angle;
}
```

To make use of the turning angle and segment length, we have to implement the following turtle operations:

- set a turtle position `x, y`
- set a turtle orientation `angle`
- move the turtle `distance` units forward in its current orientation
- add `delta` to the turtle orientation
- query the current position `x, y` of the turtle

After those operations are implemented, we can write a loop that iterates `n-1` times. In each iteration, we turn and move forward by the prescribed amounts, query the turtle position, and print the coordinates.

To implement the turtle operations, we have to store the position and orientation of the turtle. Here is an easy way to do so:

```
var turtle = { x: 0, y: 0, angle: 0 };
```

To move the turtle `distance` units forward in its current orientation, we use basic trigonometry:

```
turtle.x += Math.cos(turtle.angle) * distance;
turtle.y += Math.sin(turtle.angle) * distance;
```

Note that the trigonometric functions in JavaScript work with radians rather than degrees. There are 2π radians in a circle, hence π radians in a semicircle. If we have an angle `r` expressed in radians, the equivalent in degrees is `r / Math.PI * 180`.

When we add or subtract a value from the turtle orientation, it is possible to end up with an angle that is less than zero or greater than 2π. This does not affect our trigonometric calculations, but it can make the program difficult to debug. To ensure that the angle is always in the range [0, 2π), we can do the following whenever `turtle.angle` gets modified:

```
turtle.angle -= Math.floor(turtle.angle / (2*Math.PI)) * 2*Math.PI;
```

I have written a code snippet to demonstrate the turtle approach. Run the code by clicking the blue button below, then click and drag to draw the first segment of a polygon. You can change the number of sides by clicking on the plus and minus symbols.

```js
var Polygon = {
  color: {
    axes: '#ccc',
    sides: {
       hover: { plain: '#dddfa4', special: '#9d9c64' },
       final: { plain: '#b0c598', special: '#4f7337' }
    }
  }
};

Polygon.turtle = { x: 0, y: 0, angle: 0 };
Polygon.turtle.setPosition = function (x, y) {
  var g = Polygon,
      turtle = g.turtle,
      context = g.context,
      origin = g.origin;
  turtle.x = x;
  turtle.y = y;
  context.moveTo(origin.left + turtle.x, origin.top - turtle.y);
};
Polygon.turtle.setAngle = function (angle) {
  var g = Polygon,
      turtle = g.turtle;
  turtle.angle = angle;
};
Polygon.turtle.left = function (delta) {
  var g = Polygon,
      turtle = g.turtle;
  turtle.angle = g.normalizeAngle(turtle.angle + delta);
};
Polygon.turtle.right = function (delta) {
  var g = Polygon,
      turtle = g.turtle;
  turtle.angle = g.normalizeAngle(turtle.angle - delta);
};     
Polygon.normalizeAngle = function (angle) {
  angle -= Math.floor(angle / (2*Math.PI)) * 2*Math.PI;
  return angle;
};
Polygon.turtle.forward = function (distance) {
  var g = Polygon, 
      turtle = g.turtle,
      canvas = g.canvas,
      context = g.context,
      origin = g.origin;
  turtle.x += Math.cos(turtle.angle) * distance;
  turtle.y += Math.sin(turtle.angle) * distance;
  context.lineTo(origin.left + turtle.x, origin.top - turtle.y);
};

Polygon.resizeCanvas = function() {
  var g = Polygon,
      canvas = g.canvas,
      context = g.context,
      width = canvas.width = window.innerWidth,
      height = canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
  g.origin = { left: Math.floor(width/2), top: Math.floor(height/2) };
  g.drawAxes();
};
Polygon.drawAxes = function() {
  var g = Polygon,
      canvas = g.canvas,
      context = g.context,
      origin = g.origin,
      color = g.color;
  context.lineWidth = 2; 
  context.strokeStyle = color.axes;
  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(origin.left, 0);
  context.lineTo(origin.left, canvas.height);
  context.moveTo(0, origin.top);
  context.lineTo(canvas.width, origin.top);
  context.stroke();
};
Polygon.drawPolygon = function (situation) {
  var g = Polygon,
      canvas = g.canvas,
      context = g.context,
      turtle = g.turtle,
      color = g.color,
      n = parseInt(document.getElementById('numSides').innerHTML, 10),
      turn = 2*Math.PI / n,
      x1 = g.x1, y1 = g.y1, x2 = g.x2, y2 = g.y2,
      dx = x2-x1,
      dy = y2-y1,
      length = Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
  var angle = Math.acos(dx/length);
  if (dy < 0) {
    angle = 2*Math.PI - angle;
  }
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  g.drawAxes();
  context.lineWidth = 4;
  context.lineCap = 'round';
  context.beginPath();
  context.strokeStyle = color.sides[situation].plain;
  turtle.setPosition(x1, y1);
  turtle.setAngle(angle);
  for (var i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    turtle.forward(length);
    turtle.left(turn);
  }
  context.closePath();
  context.stroke();
  context.strokeStyle = color.sides[situation].special;
  context.beginPath();
  turtle.setPosition(x1, y1);
  turtle.forward(length);
  context.stroke();
}
Polygon.load = function () {
  var g = Polygon,
      canvas = g.canvas = document.getElementById('surface'),
      context = g.context = canvas.getContext('2d'),
      display = { begin: document.getElementById('begin'),
                  end: document.getElementById('end') },
      color = g.color;
  g.resizeCanvas();
  window.onresize = g.resizeCanvas;
  function makeUnselectable(element) {
    element.className += ' unselectable';
    element.ondragstart = element.onselectstart = function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
    };
  }
  makeUnselectable(canvas);
  var numSides = document.getElementById('numSides'),
      minus = document.getElementById('minus'),
      plus = document.getElementById('plus');
  minus.onmousedown = function () {
    var current = parseInt(numSides.innerHTML, 10);
    if (current == 3) {
      return;
    }
    numSides.innerHTML = current-1;
    g.drawPolygon('final');
  };
  plus.onmousedown = function () {
    var current = parseInt(numSides.innerHTML, 10);
    if (current == 20) {
      return;
    }
    numSides.innerHTML = current+1;
    g.drawPolygon('final');
  };
  var controls = [display.begin, display.end, numSides, minus, plus,
                  document.getElementById('options')];
  for (var i = 0; i < controls.length; ++i) {
    makeUnselectable(controls[i]);
  }
  var getPosition = function (event) {
    event = event || window.event;
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect(),
        left = event.clientX - rect.left,
        top = event.clientY - rect.top,
        origin = g.origin,
        x = left - origin.left,
        y = origin.top - top;
    return { x: x, y: y };
  };
  canvas.onmousedown = function (event) {
    document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
    var position = getPosition(event);
    g.x1 = g.x2 = position.x;
    g.y1 = g.y2 = position.y;
    display.begin.innerHTML =
        '<span class="label">x1, y1 =</span> '+g.x1+', '+g.y1;
    display.end.innerHTML = '';
    g.drawPolygon('hover');
    for (var i = 0; i < controls.length; ++i) {
      controls[i].style.zIndex = -10;
    }
    canvas.onmousemove = function (event) {
      var position = getPosition(event);
      g.x2 = position.x;
      g.y2 = position.y;
      display.end.innerHTML =
          '<span class="label">x2, y2 =</span> '+g.x2+', '+g.y2;
      g.drawPolygon('hover');
    };
  };
  function noop() {
  }
  canvas.onmousemove = noop;
  canvas.onmouseup = canvas.onmouseout = function (event) {
    if (canvas.onmousemove === noop) {
      return;
    }
    canvas.onmousemove = noop;
    g.drawPolygon('final');
    for (var i = 0; i < controls.length; ++i) {
      controls[i].style.zIndex = 0;
    }
  };
};
window.onload = Polygon.load;
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.unselectable {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-drag: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.display {
  color: #444;
  position: fixed;
  left: 40px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.label {
  color: #aaa;
}
#begin {
  top: 20px;
}
#end {
  top: 60px;
}
#options {
  position: fixed;
  left: 40px;
  top: 100px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 28px;
}
#options div {
  display: inline;
}
#options .button {
  font-size: 32px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#options .button:hover {
  color: #55838e;
}
#options .button, #numSides {
  padding: 0 5px;
}
#numSides {
  cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<div class="display" id="begin"></div>
<div class="display" id="end"></div>

<div id="options">
  <div class="button" id="minus">&minus;</div><div
       id="numSides">6</div><div
       class="button" id="plus">&plus;</div>
</div>

<canvas id="surface"></canvas>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. But unfortunately I cannot use turtle !  I just need to findout the remaining co-ordinates. Do you have some idea how to calculate the remaining co-ordinates? the regular polygon has to be constructed in anti-clockwise direction.

Comment: I didn't tell you to use an existing turtle library. I said that you have to implement the turtle operations above to calculate the remaining coordinates. There are only five turtle operations. Do you see how to implement these operations? It's a matter of converting [polar coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system) into [Cartesian coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system).

Comment: I have edited my answer to show how the turtle operations can be implemented. I have also added a code snippet that implements the turtle approach in an interactive demonstration.

Comment: Wow ! awesome answer !  really great. This answer solved my problem...thank you very much for your time and effort. I am sorry that I cannot vote up multiple times :-)

Answer (score 2):

If number of sides is N and polygon side is defined by coordinates  (x1, y1) and (x2, y2), then middle point of this side is

```
(mx, my) = ((x1+x2)/2, (y1+y2)/2)
```

perpendicular vector (left one for anticlockwise order) is

```
(px, py) = (-(y2-y1), x2-x1)
```

unit perpendicular vector

```
(nx, ny) = (px/Len, py/Len), where Len = Sqrt(px*px + py*py)
```

[apothem length](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_polygon#Circumradius)

```
  ApoLen = Len / (2*Tan(Pi/N))
```

apothem vector

```
(ax, ay) = ApoLen * (nx, ny) = (px / (2 * Tan(Pi/N)), py / (2 * Tan(Pi/N)))
```

polygon centher coordinates are

```
(cx, cy) = (mx, my) + (ax, ay)
```

circumradius

```
  R = ApoLen / Cos(Pi/N)
```

Starting angle for vertice (x1, x2) is

```
  BaseAngle = ArcTan2(y1 - cy, x1 - cy)
```

and ith vertice (one-based numbering) has angle

```
 Ai = BaseAngle + (i - 1) * 2 * Pi / N
```

and coordinates

```
  (xi, yi) = (cx + R * Cos(Ai), cy + R * Sin(Ai))
```